# RegEx to ignore results preceeded by # in any position

Tags: c, regex

Little context: I'm coding some RegEx string substitution in C, using the **POSIX** [regex library](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regexec.html).
(Thanks to @Jonathan Leffler for the clarification)

I've managed to complete the code for the actual substitution, but I'm struggling with the RegEx itself.

My aim is to find a word (namely, 'parameter') in a long string (it's actually a file read and stored as string). I know the word is on a line, but it could be preceeded or followed by other characters and I'd like to ignore all results that are preceeded by `#` in any of the position before the first letter of the word
An example containing all the cases I've thought about:

```
# default parameter
parameter=3
someparameter=3
a parameter=3
###parameter=3
# ## parameter=3
## # parameter=3
#       parameter=3
#      parameter=3
something something #   parameter=3
         parameter=3
#something parameter=3
# something parameter=3
parameter=#3
parameter=
```

I've quickly found something for the standard cases: `^\s+parameter=[0-9]+`, then moved on to tune this to achieve what I want.

After much needed research, I've ended up with using negative lookbehinds, while also discovering that the caret `^` *does not work* as intended because the word is not at the start of the string (which, again, is the start of the file).

Now I'm currently at this:

`(?<!\#)(?<!\#\s)(?<!\w)parameter=[0-9]+`

- `(?<!\#)` to ignore results preceeded by `#`
- `(?<!\#\s)` to ignore results preceeded by `#`
- `(?<!\w)` to ignore results preceeded by any other word character (as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

but as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/LfiFrr/2), it still matches some words preceeded by `#`.

Is there any way to achieve what I've described?

A fine one would be to catch any leading whitespaces (if any), but **only if** there's not a  `#` before. But this is not a strict requirement for me, I can also leave them be.

EDIT: following @Blindy's suggestion, here's what I'd like to do

### Examples of lines in which to match "parameter"

```
parameter=1
a parameter=12
parameter=345 # some comment
      parameter=4
parameter=5 ####
```

### Not to match

```
#parameter=0
# parameter=11
something # parameter=22
# something else parameter=3333
### something parameter=4312
#      parameter=543
```

Comment: Saying "the `regex` library" is ambiguous — which regex library.  There are many.  If you mean the POSIX [`regcomp()` and `regexec()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regexec.html) functions, say "the POSIX `regex` library".  If you are using negative lookbehinds, you are probably using [PCRE2](https://pcre.org/) — you shouldn't be using PCRE (version 1) in new code.

Comment: Do you have to do this in the regexp itself? I would read the input line by line, remove everything starting with `#`, do the replacement, then add back the part that was removed.

Comment: thanks @JonathanLeffler, I did not think about the different versions (I'm not an expert of regex)... I've add your info to the question

Comment: @Barmar not strictly, but for my application the file is opened just once and read all together, so what I end up with is a single string

Comment: You can split it into lines by searching for newline characters.

Comment: The standard POSIX regex library supports the regular expressions documented under [Regular Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).  That definitely does not include positive or negative look-ahead or look-behind.  That is a feature of Perl regular expressions, and hence PCRE.  You might have a somewhat (or majorly) extended set of POSIX regular expressions available on your system, but then the details matter once more.  Most likely, your code is looking for something completely different from what you expected, hence the failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give a list of example lines for a regex, you should say what you expect should happen for them, because what you have in your question is completely unusable.

So with that in mind, my *guess* of what you want would be simply something like this:

```
^[^#]*?\b(parameter=[0-9]+)
```

Ie, any parameter expression that's not preceeded by `#`. You can see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/a21ram/1

Comment: What's the `?` for? It didn't make sense to me following a `*`, so I fed your regex with/without the `?` to the data [in perl]. It produced the same results. But, online, without `?`, it misses on `a parameter=3`

Comment: So, let me get this straight, instead of trying to look up what the `*?` operator is (non-greedy repeat), you removed it and reported that it missed a parameter? I mean yes, I know that, that's why it's there.

Comment: No, it missed a parameter online but worked just fine in perl. Meaning that, in perl, it seems to be superfluous

Comment: @Blindy I'll try to be more clear in the question, thank you!
In the meanwhile, as I said in C it seems that the caret `^` character does not work in my case, since the parameter is not at the end of the "stringified" file

Comment: @Blindy I've added something, let me know if it's clearer..
In the meanwhile, in rexeg101 your expression seems to be what I'm looking for! I'll try again in C to see and confirm if the caret is really unusable in my case (to point at the start of the string, at least) of it was simply my regex that did not work

Comment: I've tried this but did not work... I've researched a bit and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46747935/5627942) to a SO question, where it's stated that `\b` is not supported by the POSIX... Is there some equivalent format I'm not aware of? Otherwise I might have to give up this way...

Comment: An equivalent without `\b` is `^[^#]*?(?<!\w)(parameter=[0-9]+)`, for example, but you should definitely drop your library if in the last twenty years it hasn't yet managed to implement a proper PCRE regex engine. The C++ STL has a built in regex library that supports everything correctly.

Comment: I will however warn you that after a quick glance at the link to your library and what it does support, it doesn't seem to have implemented negative look-behinds (`(?<!`) nor even standard character classes (`\w`). I don't have a solution that will work for you, except to reiterate that you should absolutely drop that unmaintained garbage and use a modern regex library.

Comment: @Blindy thanks a bunch for all the useful information! I'll try to ditch the unmaintained library ASAP, but unfortunately for now it's not my call...
Anyway, I've managed to use `^[^#]*?(^|[^[:alpha:])(.*)($|[^[:alpha:]]*)parameter=[0-9]+` while considering only a line at a time! So I've marked this as an answer and hopefully I'll be able to use a more modern library soon enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading lines from a file (or standard input), the normal way to deal with comments is to delete them using [`strchr()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strchr.html) to find the start of the comment:

```
char *hash = strchr(line, '#');
if (hash != NULL)
    *hash = '\0';
```

Or using [`strcspn()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcspn.html):

```
line[strcspn(line, "#")] = '\0';`
```

You can zap the newline too (or instead) if you add it to the second argument to `strcspn()`).

Then apply a simple regex with no look-behind needed to find the information you're interested in.  Work on a copy of the line if need be.

If you wanted to, you could use a regex such as `[[:space:]]*#` to find where to delete from; that strips any spaces before the `#` too.  It probably isn't necessary, though.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind, but for now I'm not reading the file a line at a time. I'll think about this if the option will be available, thanks

Comment: Why aren't you reading the file a line at a time, and how are you reading it instead?  Is it all in a single hunk of memory?  You can't be doing 'character at a time' because regexes don't work a character at a time.  If you've got all the data in a single chunk of memory, arrange to make copies of lines out of the chunk, breaking at the newlines, and then delete the comment from the copy and apply the regex.  As I noted above in a comment to the question, POSIX regular expressions do not support look-ahead or look-behind, so you won't succeed trying to use that notation with that library.

Comment: Hmmm…I see that you've [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71971280/regex?noredirect=1#comment127180495_71971280) in the question that you've slurped the entire file into memory.  So, scan the memory in line-sized chunks.  What you're trying to do is very hard, even with PCRE, when working with the whole file at once. What you're trying to do is much, much, much simpler if you split the data into lines (make copies of segments of the data in line-sized chunks), then zap the comments and only apply the matching regex after they're gone.

Comment: I'm actually doing this now! Since the "original" string is still the whole file content, I'm splitting it in more substrings based on the `\n` character.. Now it's only a matter of regex, I believe...